# Ranquear os índices de uma lista em Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Por exemplo tenho uma lista

```
[6,4,3,9,1]
```

a resposta disso seria o índice do maior valor desta lista em ordem exemplo pra lista de cima

```
[1,3,2,0,4]
```

esses são os índices dos locais onde os índices deles estão, eu fiz assim até agora:

```
def Cria_listas(tl,tv):
    valor = []
    if tv >= 1:
       for i in range(tl):
          valor = valor + [random.randint(0,tv]
       print(valor)
       return Fromint(valor)

def Fromint(n):
   indice = []
   for i in range(len(n)):
      indice = [n.index(max(n))] + indice

Cria_listas(5,99)
```

eu consigo achar o indice do maior valor, mas como acho os proximos

Comment: Não entendi, quer retornar uma nova lista com os índices dos elementos ordenados?

Comment: Em vez de `[1,3,2,0,4]` não deveria ser `[1,2,3,0,4]`?

Answer (score 0):

```
lista = [6,4,3,9,1]

#lista com os valores em ordem decrescentes e sem valores repetidos
lista_decrescente = list(set(lista))
lista_decrescente.sort(reverse=True)

lista_indicies = [None]*len(lista)

indicie = 0
for num in lista_decrescente:
    for i in range(0, len(lista)):
        if lista[i] == num:
            lista_indicies[i] = indicie
            indicie += 1

>>> print(lista_indicies)
[1, 2, 3, 0, 4]
```

Comment: Isso mesmo, obrigado pela resposta, ontem eu consegui fazer de outra maneiro, só que assim ta bem mais simples, obrigado por tirar minha duvida